# How to capture Docker's localhost traffic?

Tags: proxy, docker

I have my container spinning up which is XML API, for debugging purposes i just need proxying messages going to my docker's localhost in and out.

As far as I know, I can run it with `run --net host` to share my host network namespaces.

For some reasons my proxy (Charles) can't see incoming messages coming from docker container.

`docker run -dit --net=host --name tracks staannoe/tracks 127.0.0.1:8090`

The docker host is running Windows 7.

Comment: I cant remember the details but on Windows I had to map a network route from 172.17.0.0 to 10.0.75.2 and one of them is the IP address of the virtual network card, which you can get from network settings

Comment: Wireshark has a feature to capture loopback interface with some MITM tech. Install npcap with lookpback interface.